# Hide a field in silverlight data form with data annotations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, silverlight

Which `DataAnnotation` attribute can I use to instruct the silverlight data form not to show that field?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Display(AutoGenerateField = false)]
public String _id;